# mount: special device does not exist

Tags: linux, debian, mount

I want to mount an *.iso image onto a Debian Buster OS. I have tried the following commands

```
sudo mkdir /media/iso
sudo mount /Downloads/lv2019SP1full-linux-mac.iso /media/iso -o loop
```

but doing so I receive the following error:

"mount: /Downloads/lv2019SP1full-linux-mac.iso: failed to setup loop device: No such file or directory"

However, if I go to that directory I see this specific files there.

My end goal is to run the installer with this image. Am I doing it wrong / should I not assume to use a loop device? Are there other options I should be considering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suspecting that your "Download" directory is in your home directory. If that's the case remove the leading slash from your iso file name:

```
sudo mount -r -o loop Downloads/lv2019SP1full-linux-mac.iso /media/iso
```

or

```
sudo mount -r -o loop ~/Downloads/lv2019SP1full-linux-mac.iso /media/iso
```

"/Downloads" would be a "Downloads" directory on the top level (root of the filesystem tree).